# Nagging for upvotes

Tags: discussion

Is it generally prohibited or just considered to be in poor taste? I am pretty sure I've nagged to accept or to close or to self-answer; but I am pretty diplomatic about it so as to prevent from appearing like I'm asking for awarded rep.

Example:

[How PHP 5.4 support patch for Magento helps?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15413/how-php-5-4-support-patch-for-magento-helps#comment23193_15418)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are my 0.02$.
**Voting**
I see there is a (more or less) general trend to hardly vote on this website. [And this is a bad thing .](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/146).
This reflects in the badges section:

*Question badges*
[image: Question badges]

*Answer badges*
[image: Answer badges]

Far less than what I expected after one year of life.

People should be encouraged to vote but....

**Begging for upvotes** should be prohibited because we can end up with most of the comments looking like "Please upvote me".
I think we should mark this kind of comments for moderator's attention (any opinion from a mod on this?)

We should find an other way of encouraging people to upvote.

**Accepting answers**
I encourage people with low rep to accept answers because I'm thinking they are new here and don't exactly know how tings work. But I try not overdoing it.

Also from time to time, when I see a user with a lot of questions that have answers and don't accept them, I tell them to work on their acceptance rate.

**Conclusion**
'beg for votes' - big 'No-No'
'nudge' people to accept answers - small 'yes-yes'

Someone doesn't like my approach? Feel free to challenge it. I'm open for negotiations.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Thanks.

Comment: +1. Please keep flagging nagging for up-votes.